# How to get inverse of DFT log spectrum using opencv android?

Tags: android, opencv, fft, dft

I am new in opencv and image processing. In need to get inverse fourier of log spectrum and access the pixel's value using opencv android. I searched over internet and I didn't find answer. Here is my code

```
Mat out=DFT(ImageMat);
Mat lastoutput=IFFT(out);


private Mat DFT (Mat singleChannel) {
int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(singleChannel.rows());
int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(singleChannel.cols()); 


Imgproc.cvtColor(singleChannel, singleChannel, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


Mat padded = new Mat();
singleChannel.convertTo(singleChannel, CvType.CV_64FC2);

Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(singleChannel, padded, 0, m - singleChannel.rows(), 0,
        n - singleChannel.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
planes.add(padded);
planes.add(Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1));

Mat complexI = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);

Mat complexI2 = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);

Core.merge(planes, complexI);

Core.dft(complexI, complexI2);

Core.split(complexI2, planes);

Mat mag = new Mat(planes.get(0).size(), planes.get(0).type());

Core.magnitude(planes.get(0), planes.get(1), mag); 

Mat magI = mag;
Mat magI2 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
Mat magI3 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
Mat magI4 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());
Mat magI5 = new Mat(magI.size(), magI.type());

Core.add(magI, Mat.ones(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1), magI2);
Core.log(magI2, magI3);

return magI3;
}

private Mat IFFT (Mat res) {
Mat padded = new Mat();

int m = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(res.rows());
int n = Core.getOptimalDFTSize(res.cols()); 

Imgproc.copyMakeBorder(res, padded, 0, m - res.rows(), 0, n - res.cols(), Imgproc.BORDER_CONSTANT);

List<Mat> planes = new ArrayList<Mat>();
planes.add(padded);
planes.add(Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1));

Mat complexI = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);

Mat complexI2 = Mat.zeros(padded.rows(), padded.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);

Core.merge(planes, complexI);

//Core.idft(complexI, complexI2);
Core.idft(complexI, complexI2, Core.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT + Core.DFT_SCALE, res.rows());

Core.split(complexI2, planes);
complexI2= planes.get(0);

return complexI2;   
}
```

But, pixel output value of IDFT seems odd. What did I do wrong?

Comment: In what way is the pixel value odd? Could you post up images of the original image and the resulting image from the idft operation?

Comment: I've edited my code. I just need the pixel value of IDFT operation for another operation to identification motion blur length. I compared my code's result with Matlab. Pixel value of log spectrum is looks fine (same with Log of Matlab FFT2 function output), but not with IDFT operation. The result is too high (different with Matlab's IFFT of Log FFT2). I've tried normalized it dividing by 255 but the result is still not same. That's what I say the pixel value seems odd.

Comment: Not sure how else to help - perhaps there are different implementations between Android idft and the Matlab implementation.  I would recommend using a small 2d array size and actually graphing the differences between the two implementations to see if there is an obvious correlation between the two results.

Comment: Then, how to do IDFT of result of DFT using opencv android? How to get IDFT with the right way? I'm always thought my IDFT code is incorrect. I'm a newbie, got confused easily. Pls help

Comment: I've put a little test together of just 16 numbers and performed a dft and then idft on the result. To get the original you need to scale the results of idft with the number of data points. The function can do this for you as follows:  Core.idft(complexDest, complexiDftResult, Core.DFT_SCALE, 0);